# What does if (!msize) mean?

Tags: c

I am trying to figure out the meaning of the following codes.

In here `if (!msize)` checking to see if `msize` is zero or if `msize` is `NULL` ?

```
if (!msize)
    msize = 1 / msize; /* provoke a signal */

//Example 1: A division-by-zero misuse, in lib/mpi/mpi-pow.c of the Linux kernel, where the entire code will be optimized away. 
//Compilers, GCC 4.7 and Clang 3.1
```

Comment: msize is the number of limbs.  A number, not a pointer.

Comment: You can't divide by a pointer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (msize == 0)
    msize = 1 / msize; /* provoke a signal */
```

It's checking if `msize` is 0, and is equivalent to writing `if (msize == 0)`. If it is, it deliberately performs a divide by zero.

Answer (score 2):

It means "If msize  is EQUAL to 0". Remember that NOT in this instance is a logical operator. Also NULL is a standard MACRO in C.

However if msize is a boolean, then "`if (!msize)`" is equivalent to "`if (msize == false)`".

**On a side note:-**

**5.6 Multiplicative operators**

> 4) The binary / operator yields the quotient, and the binary %
>   operator yields the remainder from the division of the first
>   expression by the second. **If the second operand of / or % is zero the
>   behavior is undefined**; otherwise (a/b)*b + a%b is equal to a. If both
>   operands are nonnegative then the remainder is nonnegative; if not,
>   the sign of the remainder is implementation-defined79). (emphasis
>   mine)

---

Also you may get the result as **1.#IND000** which is basically the representation of **NaN**, basically IND is the representation of NaN ( Not a Number ) in Windows system. IND stands for "indeterminate form", mostly result from illegal operation like divided by zero.

Answer (score 2):

**if(!msize) is simply opposite of if(msize)**
here 
      if(!msize)  this expression becomes true if msize==0 or NULL...